# How to naturally convey the concept of a tour?

Tags: vocabulario

In English, we have tours, such as

- Movie Studio Tour (where you see how movies are made)
- History tour (where you go around, for example, a city and a tour guide tells you
  all the history behind a building)

How would you translate these in Spanish?

---

### My research

**1. EU dictionary**

The [EU dictionary](https://iate.europa.eu/search/standard/result/1597930410090/1) tends to use different words for tour

For example:

- city tour -> visita de la ciudad
- train tour -> circuito en tren
- study tour -> viaje de estudios
- bicycle tour -> paseo en bicicleta

There seems to be a rule on how to use which word, but I am not sure what that rule is.
I am also not sure which of these words I should use for "Movie Studio Tour" and "History Tour"

**2. Spanish Dict**

Spanish Dict [also lists multiple options for Tour](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tour) adding both recorrido and  gira. Again then it's not clear when you would use one option over the other.

**3. Google**

Googling around I can find "Recorrido histórico" on several sites such as [Visit Berlin](https://www.visitberlin.de/es/geschichtsparcours-recorrido-historico) and a [University site](https://www.utadeo.edu.co/es/link/observatorio-de-comunicacion/268311/recorrido-historico). I can also find  "visita estudio de cine" on a page about [Pinewood](http://ultimodiario.com/verNoticias.aspx?Id=8251) studios and [Travel Agency page](https://www.travelagenciesfinder.com/MA/Boumalne/880510868657348/Dadestravel-Organisation-viajes-al-deseirto)

**Conclusion**

So on the basis of all of this, I think that:

- History Tour would be "Recorrido histórico"
- Movie Studio Tour would be "visita estudio de cine"

However, I am not sure if this is correct and why one uses `recorrido` and the other uses `visita`

Comment: Presumably a movie studio remains stationary so you visit it whereas a history tour presumably involves going round a few sites of some connected historical interest. If the history tour went all round the Mediterranean it might be a _viaje_  I suppose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the most used word, at least in Spain, is: **tour**.

Notice that such word is taken from French into English and Spanish.
Here in Spain we use it because those guided visits are mainly oriented to foreign visitors but it's also registered in our language as you can check in the DRAE.

> [tour](https://dle.rae.es/tour)
> Voz fr. (from French)
>  1. m. gira.

Those that you have pointed are synonyms of **tour** in most contexts: tour, gira, itinerario, ruta, visita.

I can see no difference in your two examples. Usually they both are a **guided visit** to a place, being it the historic part of a city or a movie studio. They don't let you alone wandering in the movie studio, you are part of a **guided group** of visitors.

"Guided visit". You can use such terms in Spanish as well as tour: **visita guiada**.

EN History Tour
ES Tour Histórico = Visita Histórica = Ruta Histórica

In the case of "Movie Studio Tour", we have to use additional particles to describe that visit: tour por el estudio, visita por el estudio. But if you're there in the studio it probably is just signaled as tour/visita guiada.

Extra link: Some of the pages that you have linked are not Spanish. The terms that you have quoted seems right to me but usually you can not fully trust their translations. You can check [this page](https://exploramalaga.com/es/) of a tourist guide group here in my hometown (Málaga, Spain) and compare yourself the differences between the Spanish and the English versions.

Answer (score 0):

"Vuelta", as used in the sport of cycling, has some wider connotations of a circuit of various places or points of interest, events etc.